# Problem understanding the standing wave in linear antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am reading [Classical Electricity And Magnetism](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Classical_Electricity_And_Magnetism_seco/lFiXu7hNUmcC) by Wolfgang K. H. Panofsky and Melba Phillips, and in particular the section on antennae in chapter 14.

I understand the current in the antenna should vanish at the end points and have a structure of standing wave. The problem is how to derive equation 14.54:

$$ \mathbf{j}_0 (x',y',z') = J_0 ~ \delta(y')\delta(z') \frac{\sin[k(L/2 - |x'|^2)}{\sin(kL/2)} $$

Does it have to do something solution  of sound waves in organ pipe or what? Please  explain. $L/2$ is the length of antenna from central feed.

Comment: The formula looks dimensionally incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the Balanis's book (C.A. Balanis, "Antenna theory- Analysis and design", John Wiley and Sons Inc), the sinusoidal form is experimentally verified fact.
As long as I know, it seems there is no mathematical proof.

The following statements are taken from Balanis' book:

### 4.5.1 Current Distribution

For a very thin dipole (ideally zero diameter), the current distribution can be written,
to a good approximation, as
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{I}_l(x'=0,y'=0,z')=
\begin{cases}
\hat{\mathbf{a}}_zI_0\text{sin}\left[k\left(\frac{l}{2}-z'\right)\right],\;\;\;(0\leq z'\leq l/2)\\
\hat{\mathbf{a}}_zI_0\text{sin}\left[k\left(\frac{l}{2}+z'\right)\right],\;\;\;(-l/2 \leq z'\leq 0)
\end{cases} \text{      (4-56)}
\end{equation*}
This distribution assumes that the antenna is center-fed and current vanishes at
the end points ($z'=\pm l/2)$. Experimentally, it has been verified that the current in a
center-fed wire antenna has sinusoidal form with nulls at the end points.
For $l=\lambda/2$ and $\lambda/2<l<\lambda$ the current distribution (4-56) is shown plotted
in Figures 1.16(b) and 1.12(c), respectively. The geometry of the antenna is that shown in Figure 4.5